# ImageMagick - convert fails

Tags: imagemagick, carrierwave, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to use CarrierWave in ruby, and it keeps failing.
I managed to reproduce the error with `convert` utility.

```
> convert file.jpg file.bmp
convert: unable to load module `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.7-3/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1302.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: no images defined `file.bmp' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

But I see the file the jpeg.la did exist.
I installed ImageMagick using Homebrew (brew install ImageMagick), tried to upgrade to the latest and still it fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're probably missing some dependencies. For `jpeg` look at this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/211627/how-to-add-support-for-the-jpeg-image-format

Comment: Maybe try `brew rm imagemagick; brew install jpeg; brew install imagemagick`

Comment: Mark - tried this and doesn't work.
It happens to two devs I know as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading **imagemagick@6** instead of the plain **imagemagick** formula.

---

Around December 2016/January 2017 carrierwave used rmagick, which relied on version **6**  of ImageMagick. Around the same time, brew moved to version **7** of ImageMagick. This [busted rmagick](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/8756) and carrierwave functionality, so the [Hombebrew/core-brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core) project kindly [added an imagemagick@6](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/b62c3d2adf9080698139ca0562cdb93f6f38056b) formula.

The quick and dirty fix to get carrierwave running was `brew install imagemagick@6 && brew link imagemagick@6 --force`.

If this is the case, then `brew upgrade imagemagick` will not update the library that rmagick is using. Rather `brew upgrade imagemagick@6` would be necessary.

---

An alternative route may be switching from using [rmagick](https://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick) to [mini_magick](https://rubygems.org/gems/mini_magick). The mini_magick gem seems to be better maintained as of this writing (2017-Oct-03) as well as appearing to work with the most recent version of imagemagick.